# Deactivate middleware at runtime in django

Tags: django, django-middleware

Is it possible to deactivate a `middleware` on `runtime` (after starting the application) in `django`?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend toggling the middleware from within the middleware with something like [Waffle](http://waffle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or [Gargoyle](http://gargoyle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: However, if you are using a RDBMS, I recommend storing information about disabled/enabled features in some kind of in-memory storage to avoid hitting DB on each request.

Comment: I actually looking for a direct way in order to prevent some redundant works, but this can be a choice some way.

Comment: You can hot-edit the settings but it's not a good idea, the settings are assumed to be static by most applications so it could lead to strange bugs.